Snap multiple selected edges independently and not proportionally
I have the given design however the back part (edge highlighted in yellow) is angled and I need it to be flat (i.e. green line), which requires me to move it in the x direction. I simply need to modify the x value of all highlighted values to pull them out and flatten them to the edges (most extreme point).
I tried doing a move with local transform and with snap edge enabled, then I select the x edge. However if I highlight each individual edge this works properly. If I try to highlight all back edges (yellow region) and move it, it moves all edges proportionally and I never get a flat back.


Select a vertex which has a correct X coordinate and press Shift S > cursor to selected.
Set the pivot point as 3D cursor.
Select all vertices you want to affect, press S, X, 0, Enter.
